# Reproducable bootstrap samples

Tags: r, random-forest, decision-tree, resampling

I'm trying to write a resampling function (random sampling some data with replacement to create bootstrap samples) that returns a set of say b = 5 bootstrap samples. Of course, the 5 bootstrap samples are supposed to be different - but I'd like the returned set of 5 samples to be identical every time I run the procedure (i.e. the first sample would be identical to the other first sample when I run the function again, etc.) --> reproducability ...

Is this possible? I thought about changing seeds, but I found that this would be bad practice.

Please respect that I cannot use any existing packages such as "boot" - I'm doing this for a grad course in statistics, the aim is to develop the main concepts ourselves.

```
bootstrap <- function(data) {
  rows <- sample(1:nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
  bs <- data[rows,]
  rownames(bs) <- 1:nrow(data)
  bs
}

manySamples <- function(data, b) {
  bootSet <- list()
  i <- 1
  while(i <= b) {
    bs <- bootstrap(data)
    ele <- paste("bs", i, sep = "")
    bootSet[[ele]] <- bs
    i <- i + 1
  }
  bootSet
}

set1 <- manySamples(trainData, 5)
set2 <- manySamples(trainData, 5)

identical(set1, set2)
# FALSE
```

FYI: I need this to create a random forest algorithm, that creates b classification trees on the set of b bootstrap samples.

Thanks a lot for your help!
Cheers, Stefan

Comment: If you hard coded the bootstrapping, then they wouldn't be random forests, right?  Why do you think you need this?

Comment: Just use `set.seed` before each call of `manySamples`.

Comment: Great Roland, thanks! Thought a single set.seed() before both manySamples-calls was enough :)